# Flatpickr onDayCreate add class

Tags: javascript, datepicker, flatpickr

I'm struggling with a Flatpickr's (https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/) onDayCreate event. Is here anyone who knows better **how to check if picker's date object matches any date in my array of dates?**

I have an array (or array of objects, not really sure how to call this) with dates going like this:

```
dates: {
"20161029": 3,
"20161030": 0,
"20161031": 0,
"20161101": 4,
"20161102": 4,
"20161103": 4,
"20161104": 5,
"20161105": 1,
"20161106": 0,
"20161107": 4,
"20161108": 3,
"20161109": 3,
"20161110": 4
}
```

And I would need to check if value is 0, >3 or 5 and add class to that date. Flatpickr has an example but it is using math function to randomize which dates should have new span element ([example](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/#event-onDayCreate)). But I can't configure my if else to addClass.

Comment: FYI you wouldn't call that an array or an array of objects. `dates` is an object which has a bunch of similarly-named properties (not elements in a list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a dictionary of the classes just for convenience. You can use the keys of your object as a way to retrieve the number associated to a day when the flatpickr is triggering the onCreateDay callback. With the value associated to a day, you can get the class from the dictionary and, if it's not empty, add it to the element.

I've added some explanations to the code in order to highlight some things I consider relevant.

You can check it running the script in this page (full screen if don't see it) or you can check it in this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jkntfjyr/).

Hope it helps.

```js
var dates = {
    20161029: 3,
    20161030: 0,
    20161031: 0,
    20161101: 4,
    20161102: 4,
    20161103: 4,
    20161104: 5,
    20161105: 1,
    20161106: 0,
    20161107: 4,
    20161108: 3,
    20161109: 3,
    20161110: 4
  },
  classDict = {
    0: 'redClass',
    1: 'greenClass',
    3: 'blueClass',
    4: 'greyClass',
    5: 'orangeClass'
  };

// Better always use a two digit format in your dates obj
function get2DigitFmt(val) {
  return ('0' + val).slice(-2);
}

// onDayCreate event, add class to day if date has a class
flatpickr("#dayCreate", {
  onDayCreate: function(dObj, dStr, fp, dayElem) {
    var date = dayElem.dateObj,
      // Note the + 1 in the month.
      key = date.getFullYear() + get2DigitFmt(date.getMonth() + 1) + get2DigitFmt(date.getDate()),
      value = classDict[dates[key]];
    if (value) {
      dayElem.className += ' ' + value;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.redClass {
  background-color: red !important;
}
.greenClass {
  background-color: green !important;
}
.blueClass {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
.greyClass {
  background-color: grey !important;
}
.orangeClass {
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr"></script>
<input id="dayCreate" type="text" placeholder="Select Date..">
```

**UPDATE**

The idea of the dictionary was to simplify adding/removing classes and avoid ugly switches or long ifs. However, you could easily modify the code in order to filter by value (only values greater than 3 get class) and add any class you want when the condition is met.

For instance ([**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jkntfjyr/1/)):

```
function getClass(value) {
  // Here you could put any logic you want. Ifs, add the value to a string, whatever...
    return value === 4 ? 'redClass' : 'blueClass';
}
// onDayCreate event, add class to day if date has a class
flatpickr("#dayCreate", {
  onDayCreate: function(dObj, dStr, fp, dayElem) {
    var date = dayElem.dateObj,
      // Note the + 1 in the month.
      key = date.getFullYear() + get2DigitFmt(date.getMonth() + 1) + get2DigitFmt(date.getDate()),
      value = dates[key];
    if (value > 3) {
      dayElem.className += ' ' + getClass(value);
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see in the solutions I provided, there's no need to loop over the object all the time in order to get the value associated to a date, you can get it in constant time composing the key of the date from the date that flatpickr provides while constructing the day (onCreateDay callback).

**UPDATE**

According to the documentation (or so it seems), in order to get the date of a ccurrent day inside of the onDayCreate callback, you must use properties of fp (currentYear and currentMonth) and dayElem (textContent).

However, currentMonth returns always the month that the flatpicker is currently showing, not the month of the day (the calendar can be showing november, but the day can be in october or december) so a bit of tinkering is needed to avoid marking incorrect dates.

In this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkntfjyr/2/)** you can find a solution that doesn't use dateObj and works more like the documentation says.

And here's the code:

```
// Better always use a two digit format in your dates obj
function get2DigitFmt(val) {
  return ('0' + val).slice(-2);
}

function getClass(value) {
  // Here you could put any logic you want. Ifs, add the value to a string, whatever...
  return value === 4 ? 'redClass' : 'blueClass';
}

// Adjust month depending on the month's day
function getMonth(currentMonth, dayClass) {
  return currentMonth + (dayClass.contains('prevMonthDay') ? 0 : (1 + Number(dayClass.contains('nextMonthDay'))));
}

function getDateKey(year, month, day) {
  return year + get2DigitFmt(month) + get2DigitFmt(day);
}

// onDayCreate event, add class to day if date has a class
flatpickr("#dayCreate", {
  onDayCreate: function(dObj, dStr, fp, dayElem) {
    var key = getDateKey(fp.currentYear, getMonth(fp.currentMonth, dayElem.className), dayElem.textContent),
      value = dates[key];
    if (value > 3) {
      dayElem.className += ' ' + getClass(value);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think someone didn't like this question and it's answers since everyone got one downvote at the same time. This seems to work in your fiddle, but in my case I can't use your answer since those date availability can change in the future and then I had to hardcode the styles. Meaning that in @nfreeze 's answer I can easier (in my opinion) make condition that if value is greater than ex: 3 the date gets specific class and so on. (hard to explain but hope you got the point!)

Comment: @Eljas I've updated my solution with the points you mention and some things I consider worth having in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why but my `dayElem` doesn't have `dateObj` object. So it gets undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: @Eljas are you sure that you have 4 parameters in your callback and that the last one is dayElem? If you console.log(dayElem) what do you get? (you should be getting the DOM element representing the day and it has a property dateObj set to the date it represents)

Comment: @Eljas I've updated the answer using what's supposed to be the way to get the date of a day in the calendar according to the documentation. However, it puzzles me that the previous solutions didn't work for you. Though not very "formal", they should've worked as well. Hope this last one solution is enough to solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: I see, I was earlier able to set class with these methods. But there is two problems. One as you said is the currentMonth problem with setting current month's classes to previous and next month's dates. And the other problem is with the current year. Current month problem is easy to fix by checking if prevMonth or nextMonth class exists. But with the years datepicker doesn't set any classes to them. Probably have to see if I can find better datepicker or try to get dateObj work.

Comment: @Eljas well, you could add logic in order to workaround the currentYear problem. Anyway, I don't get why dateObj is not working for you? What is the value you're getting when you console.log it?

Comment: You can go to [link](http://ilmainentraileri.jloproductions.fi/test/varaa/) to see the console log, it will be there for a while until I get this figured out.

Comment: @Eljas True, it isn't there. Maybe it's related with the version of flatpickr you're using? In my examples I was using the CDN they give you in their webpage (https://unpkg.com/flatpickr), have you tried that version? It might be that you're using old code that doesn't add the dateObj to dayElem

Comment: Yes, I just downloaded the newest version and going to try it out next. Right now im using the newest version that they have for Bower, which is 0.1 version order than CDN version. Got to see if that fixes this.

Comment: Perfect, that what it was! Now I got dateObj in my dateElem! This should have been the first thing I checked.. Wonder why they didn't have the newest version for bower downloads (actually the difference was only 0.0.1 in version numbers)... Im going to accept your answer since it was closer my implemention for this. And will post my own answer for one different way to get this job done.

Comment: Congrats! Well done! And thanks for accepting my answer, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it (intentionally verbose so you can see what's going on):

```
   var dates =  {
       20161029: 3,
       20161030: 0,
       20161031: 0,
       20161101: 4,
       20161102: 4,
       20161103: 4,
       20161104: 5,
       20161105: 1,
       20161106: 0,
       20161107: 4,
       20161108: 3,
       20161109: 3,
       20161110: 4
   };

    flatpickr("#dayCreate", {
      onDayCreate: function (dObj, dStr, fp, dayElem) {
        //because you're working with an object and not an array, 
        //we'll iterate using its keys
        var myDateKeys = Object.keys(dates);
        for (var i = 0; i < myDateKeys.length; i++) {
            var myDateKey = myDateKeys[i]; // "20161029 
            var myDateVal = dates[myDateKey]; // 3       
            var myYear = parseInt(myDateKey.substr(0, 4));
            var myMonth = parseInt(myDateKey.substr(4, 2));
            var myDay = parseInt(myDateKey.substr(6, 2));

            var myDateObj = new Date(myYear + '-' + myMonth + '-' + myDay + ' 00:00:00');
            var fDateObj = dayElem.dateObj;

            //compare with event date 

             if (myDateObj.getTime() == fDateObj.getTime()) {
                    $(dayElem).addClass('myFancyDateClass' + myDateVal);
             }
        }
    }
});
```

Then add style rules to your page to highlight the dates accordingly:

```
.myFancyDateClass0{
   color: red;
}
.myFancyDateClass1{
   color: green;
}
.myFancyDateClass3{
   color: blue;
}
.myFancyDateClass4{
   color: yellow;
}
.myFancyDateClass5{
   color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Did you try if this works, since I can't get it working? It doesn't affect day elements in datepicker. I don't get this to print anything not even with dayElem.innerHTML += '<span>add text inside date's span element</span>';

Comment: Yes, it's tested and working. I modified the example to change colors of the day. You can inspect the flatpickr-day spans and see that the classes are being added

Comment: Oh I see, there is probably error when I checked my dates objects again they are in the following format: dates{"20161103": 3, "20161104": 5 etc..} so I think my problem is "" in my keys. Do you have any quick answer to reformat my keys?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have quotes around the keys. My example works like that also. You might need to re-copy my example since I changed it. Also, don't forget to add the style rules in your css.

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you're saying. The dates in your list aren't highlighting properly. I updated the example, can you try again?

Comment: I don't know why but now it adds a class, but it is adding class "myFancyDateClass0" to every date in the picker

Comment: One more time please :) I edited the code rapid fire there for a minute. It's working like a charm on my end.

Comment: I don't know what is happening here, using that loop will loop the first date object's class to every date in the picker. Right now it's the following: `fDateObj` = 2016-11-04T00:00:00+02:00 and it gets the class for that date from the `dates` object and prints it to every `dayElem` in the picker. Have to try tackle this tomorrow.. It seems like the loop gets somehow broken in my code since this works for you?

Comment: I was able to figure out my error. It's because my `dayElem` doesn't have `dateObj`, so it gets `undefined`. Any ideas why does this happens?

Comment: Here's it is working in jsfiddle. If you it works for you please mark as the answer :) https://jsfiddle.net/2sy29ojx/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nfreeze and acontell for helping me figure this out when I think documentation for that plugin was kind of hard to understand (for me atleast).

Both answers from nfreeze and acontell worked from the start when I figured out my error with the `dayElem.dateObj`.

The error was due my older version of the plugin. I had 2.0.5 (which is currently the version for bower) and `dateObj` started working when I manually updated to version 2.0.6.

My way to actually  use this was to make new object (for my own purposes for the future use) and then use every items value for class:

```
var obj = dates,
    keys = Object.keys(obj),
    notAvailable = {},
    fewAvailable = {},
    available = {},
    value,
    date;

    var formattedDates = keys.filter(function(key) {
        if ( !obj[key]) {
          date = moment( key, 'YYYYMMDD' ).format();
          value = 'full';
          return notAvailable[date] = value;
        } else if( obj[key] < 3 ) {
          date = moment( key, 'YYYYMMDD' ).format();
          value = 'fewAvailable';
          return fewAvailable[date] = value;
        } else if( obj[key] >= 3 ) {
          date = moment( key, 'YYYYMMDD' ).format();
          value = 'available';
          return available[date] = value;
        }
 });

 var datesForPicker = Object.assign(notAvailable, fewAvailable, available);
```

And then onCreate event I used that :

```
flatpickr("#dayCreate", {
 onDayCreate: function(dObj, dStr, fp, dayElem) {

   var date = moment(dayElem.dateObj).format(),
       value = datesForPicker[date];

   if( value ){
    dayElem.className += ' ' + value;
   }

 }
});
```

Use of Moment.js is logical because I already have it in my project, the reason for moment format is to get those dates in the same format. You could do that other ways too.

Comment: I guess answering first and correctly doesn't always pay off here ;)

Comment: @nfreeze Well, that was a hard choice. But I picked the one which is close my own code.